# How to download a BMP image and Display it in ImageViewer

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask, connection, imageview

I am trying to download and display a BMP picture within my android app, The problem is when I run the app, no change happens at all... If you can give me any points that would be great! :)

Stack Trace: http://laravel.io/bin/wOyQ

Update: New code

```
public String imageUrl = "http://rory-price.co.uk/uni/images/444444.bmp";

private class LoadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer, Bitmap>
{
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        try
        {
            URL urlstring = new URL(imageUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlstring.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap myBitmap) {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        iv.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}
}
}
```

Comment: your url points to a jpg, not a bmp, apparently

Comment: `iv.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);` can't touch the views from a background thread. This should be done in `onPostExecute` for example

Comment: pointer: look at your logcat. there is a big stacktrace telling you you are touching the views from a background thread.

Comment: Updated OP,  adding the suggestions how ever still nothing :(

Comment: Please post a stacktrace from your logcat depicting any errors/warnings that you see...

Comment: http://laravel.io/bin/wOyQ Stacktrace for warnings

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
         public String imageUrl = "http://rory-price.co.uk/uni/images/444444.bmp";

 private class LoadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer, Bitmap>
 {
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params)
    {
      try
      {
        URL urlstring = new URL(imageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlstring.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();

        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, bmOptions);

        return myBitmap;
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap myBitmap) {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        iv.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}
}
}
```

And make sure you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your manifest file.

Comment: tried using this solution (see above) however no change)

Comment: I always had the INTERNET permission :( However still no change with your new code

Comment: I have no idea! :( Could you post your entire java class in case something is throwing up errors there?

Comment: are you trying to test on emulator or device?

Comment: i am trying to run it on a Nexus 7 Device